# Explain difference between foo and \(foo\)

Tags: regex, grep

```
grep "http:\/\/.*\.jpg" index.html -o
```

Gives me text starting with **http://** and ending with **.jpg**

So does: `grep "http:\/\/.*\.\(jpg\)" index.html -o`

What is the difference? And is there any condition where this might fail?

I got it to match either jpg,png or gif using this regex:

```
http:\/\/.*\.\(jpg\|png\|gif\)
```

Something to do with backreference or regex grouping that I read. Cannot understand this part `\(\)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping is used for two purposes in regular expressions.

One uses is to delimit parts of the regexp when using alternatives. That's the case in your third regexp, it allows you to say that the extension can be any of jpg, png, or gif.

The other use is for backreferences. This allows you to refer to the text that matched an earlier part of the regexp later in the regexp. For instance, the following regexp matches any letter that appears twice in a row:

```
\([a-z]\)\1
```

The backreference \1 means "match whatever matched the first group in the regexp".

Answer (score 1):

`(` and `)` are *metacharacters*. i.e. they don't match themselves, but mean something to `grep`.

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html):

> Grouping is performed with backslashes followed by parentheses ‘(’,
>   ‘)’.

so in the above the `\(` and `\)` define within them a group of possibilities to match separated by the `|` character. i.e. your filename extensions.

Comment: Alright,so how do I ignore equal to or less than signs(<>) that are included in the text before the extension. For example if the text is `http://agjfs>Image<img src="/blah.png"`